# How to cut out elements from a page with Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension that loads an `<iframe>` of another site onto the New Tab page. Right now I'm loading YouTube's subscription page (don't worry about the `Same-Origin` issue, I solved that already), but now I'm trying to cut everything out of the page except the `#content` element (the subscription feed element).

Here's my code:

**Background.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script> 
    </head>
        <iframe id="left" src="left.html" name="left"></iframe>
        <iframe id="right" src="right.html" name="right"></iframe>
</html>
```

**Left and Right .html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
    <body>   
        <input type="button" value="Load new document" id="loader">
    </body> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="window.js"></script>    
</html>
```

**Window.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById("loader").addEventListener("click", loadUrl);
});

function loadUrl()
{
    window.location = 'https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions';
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(!'#content'),function(e){
      e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
    });
    return false;
}
```

As you can see, right now I'm loading it in with a button. Once it's pressed, it loads YouTube and should cut out all the html except `#content`, but it's not. Is there another way to solve this, possibly with jQuery? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
document.querySelectorAll(!'#content')
```

won't meet your requirements, you should use the following instead if you do want to remove all elements except #content.

```
document.querySelectorAll('*:not(#content)')
```

Comment: `:not` is going to be really efficient. Rather than cutting out everything else, you should extract the one thing you *do* want.

Answer (score 1):

`#content` isn't accessible to `document`, because the global `document` is on a different page - the page containing the iframes, but not their contents. Moreover, `document.querySelectorAll(!'#content')` is not a valid selector string - that will be interpreted as `document.querySelectorAll(false)` because `!` of a non-empty string returns `false`.

You're going to have a hard time getting access to the contents of an iframe, just in general. Most browsers, like Chrome, won't event load the contents of an iframe if `X-Frame-Options` is set to `SAMEORIGIN`, which, for youtube, it certainly is.

Supposing you're getting around this (with a reverse proxy, perhaps?), you can get the contents of an iframe using JavaScript like so:

```
iframe.contentWindow.document
```

You can then use `querySelector` and friends on the iframe:

```
iframeDocument.querySelector('#content')
```

And if you want to cut out a node, you should `remove()` it:

```
iframeDocument.querySelector('#content').remove()
```

Now, having said all of that:

**Don't do this.**

You're abusing iframes, which requires some very creative (read: brittle, hacky) code, and Youtube certainly has a public API from which you can get access to someone's Youtube feed - and in a way that Youtube is far less likely to block by tightening security, or even by accident. (Suppose the HTML on their page changes, so `#content` contains everything. Or suppose they decide to check that the correct origin is requesting the page with JavaScript, and block you.)

What you want, you should use Youtube's API for.

Comment: I get around the `SAMEORIGIN` issue with the link to `script.js` from `background.html`. It cuts out `X-Frame-Options` headers since I get permissions in `manifest.json` to `webRequest` and `webRequestBlocking`. Thanks for the help! Though, I'm not sure how `remove()` would work since I want to remove everything on the page except `#content`. And it seems that there is no way to use a `not` logic gate, is there?

Comment: Also, using `document` seems to work, because I can indeed get YouTube to load in an `iFrame`, so it must be working because of the use of it on line 2 of `window.js`

Comment: So, `!` isn't a "not logic gate." A "not logic gate" is part of a circuit diagram. `!` is just a "logical not." And `document` won't work, because `document` refers to the document **on this page**, not to the `document` on the **iframe embedded page**. For that, you need to get access to the `iframe.contentWindow.document`. You are indeed loading the iframe on *this* `document`, but that doesn't mean you can access the iframe's contents. In fact, you cannot.

Comment: In the case of `remove`, I'd suggest you [clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) the `#content` DOMNode and put it somewhere else instead. Use `cloneNode(true)` and you'll get all of the stuff you want, then use `appendChild` to move it to another place.